# For $f = x^7+x+1$, find all primes $p$ for which $f_p$ ($f$ considered modulo $p$) is not separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Question from David Cox Galois Theory.

For $f = x^7+x+1$, find all primes $p$ for which $f_p$ ($f$ considered modulo $p$) is not separable. How to do this problem?

I have computed $gcd(f, f')=1$. But I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you computed, but you indeed can solve this by computing $\gcd(f, f')$.

First, $f_7$ is separable. This is true since $f_7' = 1$. Now we suppose $p \neq 7$, and $f_p' = 7x^6 + 1$.

Then $\gcd(f,f') = \gcd(x^7+x+1, x^6+7^{-1}) = \gcd(x^6+7^{-1}, x^7+x+1 - (x^7 + 7^{-1}x))$, which is $\gcd(x^6+7^{-1}, (1-7^{-1})x + 1) = \gcd(x^6+7^{-1}, 7^{-1}\cdot6x+1)$

If $7^{-1}\cdot6x + 1 = 0$ has no solution, which happens when $6$ is not invertible, i.e., $p = 2, 3$, then $f$ is separable (why?).

Now we look at the case when $p \neq 2,3,7$. In this case $7^{-1}\cdot6x + 1 = 0$ has solution $x = -7\cdot6^{-1}$. Therefore the gcd is not $1$ if this is also a solution of $x^6 + 7^{-1} = 0$. Solve this, and you get the answer of this question.

The answer will be three primes, one of them has two decimal digits, and the other two have three digits.

Comment: Thanks for the post! What do you mean by $f_p$ is invertible? Also, to solve the equation that you have provided, I get the numbers $11, 239, 331$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I actually wanted to say $f$ is separable. The number should be the same as what I got!